# Weak entities and constraints in DBMS

Tags: database, entity-relationship, rdbms

I started reading DBMS and I've this question :

There is an employee table and a weak entity set Dependents. 
[image]

By the definition, Weak Entity must have total participation with strong entity set. My question is : Can there be a dependent in dependent table who isn't in relation with employee?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, and in a perfect implementation, I'm inclined to say no, because a weak entity is not supposed to exists on its own and your database constraints will prevent that.

In practice however, depending on how you implement it and what constraints you put, then yes sure it can happen.